Effective hiking - dynamic programming
I got the following question today, and solved it suboptimally. I wanted to get some help how to get this to the most optimal solution:
The question is; A hiker needs to complete a lit of trails on record days. It needs to do at least one trail per day, but otherwise he can do as many as possible. He wants to minimise the sum of the longest trails on each day. For instance [10, 9, 2, 15, 11] and records =2 yields optimal of 25
My solution involved a simple recursive solution - for each record day, iterate from left to right, tracking maximum, and then recursively calling the function to get the result for record -1 and then keeping track of minimum:
 public static int minTrails(List<Integer> trails, int currDay, int days) {
        // Count all remaining trails
        if (days == 1) {
            return trails.subList(currDay, trails.size()).stream().mapToInt(x -> x).max().orElse(0);
        }

        int totalDays = trails.size();
        // Recursive case: Try different splits of the trails
        int maxLength = 0;
        int currMin = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

        // Try to take at least one trail, up to n - days trails for the current day
        for (int i = currDay; i <= totalDays - days; i++) {
            maxLength = Math.max(maxLength, trails.get(i));

            // Recursively solve for the remaining trails and days
            int maxOfRest = minTrails(trails, i + 1, days - 1);

            // The current result is the maximum sum of the current day and the rest of the days
            currMin = Math.min(maxLength + maxOfRest, currMin);
        }

        return currMin;
    }


This screams some form of DP. One thing which came obvious to me a bit later, is to precompute all maximums starting at trail=i until end of array. This is in fact all solutions for each subarray starting at i if record=1, i.e. just one day left to do all remaining trails. We can iterate from right to left, and keep track of maximum, storing results in an aray, yielding O(n). Then, if we need to calculate record=2 we can iterate in the same manner, starting at i=0, take one trail at the time and at each i, ask for the result for record=1 from memoization, which is O(n). So for record=2, I now have O(n) solution.
This leads to my more generalised approach. For record=3, I need to pre-compute for record=2, for each i, the optimal sub-solution. That would mean computing for each i the solution above (iterate from i to end, reuse record=1 as I go along). But that is now done for each starting point i, meaning we have O(n^2) time complexity per record day.
That means computation of record=1 is O(n), final solution is O(n) and any intermediate record days memoization takes O(n^2), yielding O(record * n^2) solution.
I want to ask if:

My modified approach actually makes sense?
It seems there should be a way for record=2 touse some right-to-left iteration to achieve O(n) computation.
Am I thinking of this problem in the wrong category in general? is there perhaps a greedy approach?


"minimise the sum of the longest trails on each day" It isn't quite clear what this means exactly. Can you show how you get 25?

it is a maximum of each day and the sum of those minimised. So for the example is 10 on first day and then all others out of which the max is 15.

Do they need to be made in the given order?

@Bober02 Can we take not 10 but, for example, 2 on the first day?

They need to be taken in the order they appear i.e. you can choose when to split but not rearrange

Can someone think of a counterexample to the greedy method whereby we take each element in descending order of magnitude and scan from it as far left and right as possible while leaving enough days as there are needed sections, to build the subarray that is the next day's trails? (We resolve the choice of more left or more right by greedily choosing whichever side would contain a greater element.)
In the example, we’d start with 15 and pick the side with the 11 to extend to, leaving the 10 as the minimal-size section needed for the other day.
10, 9, 2, 15, 11
    <———————-——>

The idea is that a local maximum will either way contribute to the result and we should use it to cover other high numbers as greedily as possible.

The idea is interesting but let's say you have 10 record days and a huge array. What is your stopping condition for extending? let's say your max element is in the missle and all other ones are way smaller. You have to leave 9 more elements. Which ones and where do you leave? Also, as you extend, you might extend past a local minimum e.g.
[5,2,8,6,1] - how would you tell to extend all the way to the left and leave 1 as one day on the right?

consider [5, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 5]

@Bober02 for the example you gave, [5, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 5], don’t we also need a number of days? I’m not sure how to answer you without it.
